# Pasar una consulta sql a query builder

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Como podria pasar la siguiente consulta a query builder?

```
SELECT SUM( DISTINCT Precios) FROM Productos;
```

Comment: Que función cumple DISTINCT? Es un poco escueta tu consulta, podrías aclarar si has armado el model de Productos, y pegarlo en la consulta.

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega lo que hayas intentado al momento